# Getting length of results returned by mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord bot which grabs data from a sql table. It then checks whether there is enough rows to complete the users request. However my code keeps erroring. Ive been looking around at the code and really have no clue why it isnt working.

This is my code

```
function getAccount(amount, type) {
    con.query("SELECT data FROM accounts WHERE type = " + type,
        function(err, result, row, fields) {
            if(result.length < Number(amount)) {
                message.channel.send(//text);
            } else {
                message.channel.send(//text);
            }
```

The code above shows this error when run 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: First check what is returning for result parameter

Comment: your result is undefined

Comment: its not when i run the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: i worked it out, missformated query :)